# PL/SQL Execute immediate how to use bind variables after "using"

Tags: oracle, plsql

Parameters coming my function starts with "p_" so i'm trying to get colum names from table and changed them to (p_city,p_number,p_country) for to use it in after "using clause"
simple ex:
execute immediate insert into ADDRESS values(:city,:number,:country) using p_city,p_number,p_country;

---

```
 for i in 1 .. v_max loop
    select t.column_name
      into v_column_name
      from user_tab_columns t
     where table_name = 'ADDRESS'
       and t.column_id = i;

    if i = v_max then
      v_values := v_values || ':' || v_column_name || ')';
      v_params := v_params || 'p_' || v_column_name;
    else
      v_values := v_values || ':' || v_column_name || ',';
             
      v_params := v_params || 'p_' || v_column_name || ',';
      end if;
    end if;
  
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_values);
  --VALUES (:city,:number,:country)      //v_values output
  dbms_output.put_line('v_params ' || v_params);
  --p_CITY,p_NUMBER,p_COUNTRY    //v_params output
  sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO ' || v_table_name || v_values;
  dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
  --INSERT INTO ADDRESS VALUES (:city,:number,:country)  //sql_stmt output
  
  
  //error comes from here : Not all variables bound. 
. execute immediate sql_stmt  using v_params; 
  //sql_stmt working good but , after "using" i can't bind variable like this.
```

---

Comment: that's not how it works.  each bind parameter needs to be a discrete value.

Comment: So there is no way ?

Comment: not with execute immediate.  you would need to use the DBMS_SQL package.

Answer (score 0):

'execute immediate' needs to know how many bind variables are going to be used.  If you know an upper limit, then you can mimic this kind of operation.  Let says you have 7 "true" bind variables to use, but you know that you'll have at most 10.

You build the following SQL

```
insert into TARGET_TABLE ( col1, col2, ...., col7)
select :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7
from dual
where :8 is null
or :9 is null
or :10 is null
```

which can then be run as:

```
execute immediate my_sql
using :myval1, :myval2, :myval3, :myval4, :myval5, :myval6, :myval7, null, null, null;
```

That way, the number of binds is fixed at your upper limit (10), and you just augment the true values with as many nulls as you need.